# TcpListener server loop to idle until there is a pending connection

Tags: c#, events, mono, tcplistener, single-threaded

For the purpose of this question, I have made a super simplified example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1337);

            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Starting listener on {0}:{1}", IPAddress.Any, 1337);

            while (true)
            {
                if (server.Pending())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Activity...");

                    Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();

                    IPEndPoint clientAddress = (IPEndPoint) client.RemoteEndPoint;

                    Console.WriteLine("Accepted client: {0}:{1}", clientAddress.Address, clientAddress.Port);

                    client.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("Closed connection to: {0}:{1}", clientAddress.Address, clientAddress.Port);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Currently takes 100% of my CPU (well, actually Core - 25%, but you get the idea).
                    // How do I idle (CPU @ 0%) the loop until pending connection?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The comment already contains the question, but yes, how do I idle the loop until there is an actual pending connection, so that my CPU is not getting melted?

Is there a way to listen and awake only on OS events when there is a pending connection on a given socket? (Something like [**libuv (node.js)**](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) does, that's why I have added [single-threaded](/questions/tagged/single-threaded))

My actual implementation is meant for a fairly basic Reactor Event Loop, but yes, I have no clue how to listen to OS events with C# (and if there is any possibility).

I'm aware of `BeginAccept` and the other bunch of Async family, but those folks are not acceptible due to their multi-threaded nature.

Also, I'm aware I could simply `Thread.Sleep` within the loop, but I'm looking for the event based behavior.

P.S. I'm working with Mono and the target is a Linux executable.

Comment: If you want to use a blocking style, you can call AcceptSocket without waiting for Pending first; the call will block (without spinning) until a connection is accepted.  Alternately, you can add a Sleep in your polling loop to reduce the CPU overhead, but it's much better when writing network I/O code to avoid polling and use the proper synchronization tools to wake up only when I/O is available.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `BeginAccept` isn't necessarily multi-threaded (at least as far as your code is concerned). If you provide a synchronization context, `AcceptSocketAsync` is extremely easy to use if you have access to `await`/`async`, and it will asynchronously handle things while using code very similar to synchronous, and completely going around multi-threading issues (since you're actually working on one thread the whole time in your code). Mono should have support for `await`/`async` now.

Comment: @Luaan, with multi-threaded I thought anything that spawns extra thread per request.

Comment: @jolt Well, `BeginAccept` doesn't, not really. It borrows a thread from the `ThreadPool`, just for an extremely short time (to put the actual callback in the invoke queue). If you call `BeginAccept` a hundred times, it *doesn't* spawn 100 threads. It just registers a hundred different asynchronous sockets. That's the beauty of IOCP - you're not using CPU threads to handle I/O-bound work. To process communication with a thousand clients, you don't need a thousand threads anymore (unlike in the "synchronous" model). It's actually pretty cool :)

Comment: I'm curious: Where did you get the idea of using Pending from? I see this mistake a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you just remove the check for pending connections and let the main thread block ([`AcceptSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket.aspx) is a blocking method) until a connection has been accepted:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client to connect...");

    Socket client = server.AcceptSocket(); // This is a blocking call...

    Console.WriteLine("Client connected...");

    IPEndPoint clientAddress = (IPEndPoint) client.RemoteEndPoint;

    Console.WriteLine("Accepted client: {0}:{1}", clientAddress.Address, clientAddress.Port);

    client.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Closed connection to: {0}:{1}", clientAddress.Address, clientAddress.Port);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the mechanism ([`Pending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that is available if you want to *avoid* waiting, and then having an issue because you wanted to wait:

```
        while (true)
        {
                Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();

                Console.WriteLine("Activity...");

                IPEndPoint clientAddress = (IPEndPoint) client.RemoteEndPoint;

                Console.WriteLine("Accepted client: {0}:{1}", clientAddress.Address, clientAddress.Port);

                client.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("Closed connection to: {0}:{1}", clientAddress.Address, clientAddress.Port);
        }
```

[`AcceptSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) blocks until it gets a connection.

Normally, after getting a connection, you'd hand the open socket off to something else (either a dedicated thread<sup>1</sup> or a pool of threads, or something else) and just get back around to calling `AcceptSocket` again so that more than one client can connect at a time.

<sup>1</sup>One thread per socket doesn't really scale well but it'll work well enough whilst you're only playing.

Comment: what would be a more appropriate technique to use rather than one socket per thread? Is there a number of sockets per thread that is reasonable? Does that number change depending on how many connections you have active?

Comment: @TheMonarch -  these days I'd usually recommend using higher level abstractions such as async mechanisms and/or Tasks and let *something else* worry about managing threads.

Answer (score -1):

The loop is going to go as fast as possible -- That's why it's taking up so many of your CPU cycles.

Try adding

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
```

in the body of your else.

The above will solve the high CPU load, but it will not solve the blocking that occurs on your main thread when you call the Sleep() method. I personally would recommend running your server loop under a new (IsBackground = true) thread. This would result in much lower CPU cycles usage AND prevent your main thread from blocking.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: This is treating the symptom (the high CPU load). Better treat the cause: The Pending call.